# How can make this adserver snippet validate to W3C standards?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, ampersand

I have a made a contract with an adserver to serve ads on my website and the html snippet they give me does not validate, I am having a hard way trying to make it validate.

My header is transitional.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The html code I was given is the following.

```
<script  language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">iwsrcplus="http://codenew.impresionesweb.com/r/banner_iw.php?idrotador=82140&tamano=160x600&lgid="+((new Date()).getTime() % 2147483648) + Math.random(); document.write("<scr"+"ipt language=javascript  type=text/javascript src="+iwsrcplus+"></scr"+"ipt>");</script><noscript><iframe src="http://alt.impresionesweb.com/noscript.php?tam=160x600&idp=82140&ref=82140&cod=160915" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></noscript>
```

It does not validate just by changing the `&` to `&amps;`.

Comment: Well what exactly does the validator say?

Comment: It's **not** `&amps;` -> it's `&amp;`.

Comment: XHTML and `document.write`? I don't think so. You're probably serving the document as `text/html`, which means your doctype is wrong, and validating it as an XML document is totally pointless.

Comment: @Pumbaa80:  After fixing the errors, his snippet validates using his Doctype.  See my answer.

Comment: @Sparky: The point is, browsers will [completely ignore the doctype](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/2000Sep/0024.html) if the document is served as text/html, which it presumably is. However, the snippet does not validate as HTML, due to the lack of CDATA there. So, validation of "XHTML" by copy&paste does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `&` symbols into...

```
&amp;
```

<s>Then post whatever other errors you get.</s>

**EDIT:**

I validated all of your code as follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
       <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script  language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        iwsrcplus="http://codenew.impresionesweb.com/r/banner_iw.php?idrotador=82140&amp;tamano=160x600&amp;lgid="+((new Date()).getTime() % 2147483648) + Math.random(); document.write("<scr"+"ipt language=javascript  type=text/javascript src="+iwsrcplus+"></scr"+"ipt>");
    //]]>
    </script>
    <noscript><iframe src="http://alt.impresionesweb.com/noscript.php?tam=160x600&amp;idp=82140&amp;ref=82140&amp;cod=160915" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></noscript>

    </body>

</html>
```